# How can I start emacs in "headless" mode?

Tags: command-line-arguments, docker

I'm configuring a `.emacs.d` folder for putting inside a Docker container. On Docker, I need to install all the tools that I want on my image while I'm building the image. Even though I can properly put my `.emacs.d` folder in the right place, I always rely on opening emacs inside the docker image (the first time after building it) and waiting it to install all the emacs packages from my `init.el` file after creating the image. I'd like to install those packages while I'm building my docker image.

Is there any emacs command I can use to run the `init.el` file from the command line? Just so my configurations will be ready to use in the docker container when I open it for the first time?

Comment: Can't you map the `init.el` file into the container, start up emacs in the container, wait for it to install all the packages and then dump that image? Then when you start a container from the dumped image, it will have everything, no?

Comment: @NickD Even though it's possible it wouldn't be the ideal solution for me. I'd like to deal with it directly on my Dockerfile. For example, with Vim I can use `vim +PlugInstall +qall` and install everything from the command line. I'd like to find something similar for emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can invoke Emacs with the `--batch` flag and pass Elisp code to evaluate using either `--eval` (`-e`) if you have an expression you'd like to evaluate, such as `(package-install 'foo)` or you could use `--script` if you wish to evaluate a file.  Note that `--batch` implies `--no-init-file`, so Emacs might not behave as it does during regular sessions.

Comment: Thanks! The line `RUN emacs --batch --script /root/.emacs.d/init.el` worked perfectly inside the `Dockerfile`.